# Hide Default Title Column via Powershell sharepoint pnp Module

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I was wondering if anyone knew how to Hide the Default Title Column when you create a new List using the Powershell Sharepoint PNP Module.

I've been trying the following

```
    $field = get-pnpfield -Identity "Title" -List "Lists/Services" -Web /
    $field.Sealed = $false
    $field.Hidden = $true
    $field.Required = $false
    $field.SetShowInDisplayForm($false)
    $field.SetShowInEditForm($false)
    $field.SetShowInNewForm($false)
    $field.update()
```

However the Title Column is still present when I reload the list.

I can remove manually by going into each List, enabling Content Types; Then hiding the column and removing it from the list view. But I plan to move 20+ excel workbooks onto sharepoint and I don't want to do it manually for each sheet/list in the workbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PnP Powershell, after you have hidden the title field and executed $field.update(), you also have to execute

```
 $field.Context.ExecuteQuery()   or  Invoke-PnPQuery
```

This will push the updates to your field

Comment: Thanks, the `Invoke-PnPQuery` really helped.... the only issue is I can't tell what I changed because I was mucking around. Ended up changing/deleting the fields "Title" and "LinkTitle" as well as trying to adjust the View. Not sure which ones worked but its finally gone.

Answer (score 1):

Run [Set-PnPField](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpfield?view=sharepoint-ps)

```
Set-PnPField -List '<listTitle>' -Identity '<ColumnName>' -Values @{Required=$false;Hidden=$true}
```

If the field is hidden, it will not display in the forms, so we don't need to set "`SetShowInDisplayForm($false); SetShowInEditForm($false); SetShowInNewForm($false)`".

PnP does not provide method to set field displayed in the list. As a workaround, create a new view and add fields using [Add-PnPView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpview?view=sharepoint-ps), then remove the old view using [Remove-PnPView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/remove-pnpview?view=sharepoint-ps).

If you don't want "Title" field any more, you can remove it from the list using [Remove-PnPField](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/remove-pnpfield?view=sharepoint-ps).

```
Remove-PnPField -List "<list>" -Identity "Title"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Shell access role or you can add yourself as a shell admin .

ADD-SPSHellAdmin . It will ask for username ,enter your name .

After this you need to add PSSnapin.

Add-PSsnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell".

Only then will you be able to run Get-SPweb command.
Try using below snippet:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity 
'http://www.spsite.com/subsite'
$List = $web.Lists['MyList']
$column = $List.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName('Title')
$column.Hidden = $true
$column.ShowInDisplayForm = $false
$column.ShowInViewForms = $false
$column.ShowInEditForm = $false
$column.ShowInListSettings = $false
$column.Update()

# To delete the column, simply add the following row
$List.Fields.Delete($column)
```

Comment: How do I get access to the `Get-SPWeb` Command? I can't install Sharepoint-server module on my desktop and I was hoping to keep it purely within the sharepoint-pnp module.

Comment: For getting access to Get-SPweb two things that are necessary. One you should have shell access role on the database of the webapplication that you want to query using Get-SPweb. Second thing you will need to add PSSnapin like this.     ADD-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" .  The code written by Ganesh above fails if you do not have this 2 things ticked.